Why is $\dim\ker(A-\alpha I)^k-\dim\ker(a-\alpha I )^{k-1}$ the number of $\alpha$-Jordan blocks of size at least $k$?
Why is $\dim\ker(A-\alpha I)^k-\dim\ker(a-\alpha I )^{k-1}$ the number of $\alpha$-Jordan blocks of size at least $k$
I found this Mathstackexchange explanation but don't quite follow the argument in its entirety. For an $\alpha$-jordan block $J_n(\alpha)$, I get that $J_n(\alpha)-\alpha I=J_n(0):=J$, and it is well understood from properties of $J=J_n(0)$ that
$$\dim \ker J^k - \dim \ker J^{k-1} =\begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if $1\leqslant k\leqslant n$ } \\ 0 & \text{ if $k>n$. }\end{cases}$$
But all I can deduce from this is that for $1≤k≤n$, each step adds exactly one new dimension to the kernel, corresponding to a new generalised eigenvector. How exactly does this translate back to answering the original question of why $$\dim\ker(A-\alpha I)^k-\dim\ker(a-\alpha I )^{k-1}$$ represents the number of $\alpha$-jordan blocks of size at least $k$?
Edit:
I tried to explain the result using a diagram that I drew:
I actually tried drawing my own diagram too.
Suppose we knew the sizes of all the Jordan blocks of some JNF(A) before-hand. Then we can represent this in the following diagram:

I use words of lumps $\frown$ to try visualise the chains/strings, since each $\alpha$-jordan block corresponds to a $\alpha$-jordan chain/string. The chains goes from left to right, with the left-most node representing an eigen-vector, and the right-nodes of each $\frown$ representing a pre-image/generalised eigenvector. In the example above, for the $\alpha$-jordan blocks $J_1(\alpha), J_2(\alpha)$ we have 3 $\frown$s each, meaning for all $k>n=4$, $$\ker(A-\alpha I)^k-\ker(A-\alpha I)^{k-1}=\emptyset$$, i.e., our Kernel sequence stabilizes/we have reached the ends of the longest $\alpha$-chains extant within JNF(A).
From this representation, it seems clear to me that for each $1\leq k \leq n$ $$\text{num of }\alpha-\text{Jordan blocks of size } \geq k=\dim\ker(A-\alpha I)^k-\dim\ker(A-\alpha I)^{k-1}.$$
Can someone please verify that this reasoning is sound?
